# How to increase line chart width in ng2-charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, linechart, ng2-charts

I am trying to render a line chart using `"ng2-charts": "^2.3.0"` and `"chart.js": "^2.8.0"`,. Chart is displaying as expected but only problem is that I am not able to increase the line width with `borderWidth` property.

**Code:**

```
import { SingleDataSet, Label, Color } from "ng2-charts";
import { ChartType, ChartOptions } from "chart.js";

public barChartType1: ChartType = "line";


  public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
       {
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: '',
          fontSize: 20,
         }
       },
      ]
    
    },
    
    elements: {
      point:{
          radius: 0,
          borderWidth: 50
      }
    },
  };


  public lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      borderColor: '#5081bd',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  ];
```

**Template:**

```
                        <canvas baseChart  height="30vh" width="80vw"
                            [colors]="lineChartColors" 
                            [datasets]="barChartDataSets1[customdata.index]"
                            [labels]="barChartLabels1[customdata.index]" 
                            [options]="lineChartOptions" 
                            [chartType]="barChartType1" 
                            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" 
                            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
                        </canvas>
```

**Inputs:**

```
barChartDataSets1 [{"data":["2.00","2.00","2.00","2.00","2.00","2.00","2.00","2.00"]
barChartLabels1 [" "," "," ","ans1"," "," "," ","ans2"]
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Is there any solution for this and why changing `borderWidth` property isn't working on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you placed the option in the wrong namespace instead of using `options.elements.point` you need to place it in `options.elements.line`:

```js
elements: {
  point: {
    radius: 0,
  },
  line: {
    borderWidth: 8
  }
},
```